# Unwanted lines in border-image where image parts connect

Tags: html, css, border, border-image

When using CSS property `border-image`, I get these unwanted 1px borders where the different image parts connect. Depending on the window size, these lines might appear or not. Is there a way to get rid of them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I had to add `fill` to property `border-image-slice`.